# Unit testing for uploading to S3

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-s3, junit

I'm having trouble writing unit tests for a method that overwrites a file to a S3 bucket. The method grabs the original metadata of the file, and then overwrites the file with a new modified version and the same original metadata.

What I want the test to do is verify the inner methods like `getObjectMetadata` and `putObject` are called correctly with the right parameters

Here is the method:

```
 public void upload(File file, String account, String bucketName) {
        String key = "fakekey";
        ObjectMetadata objMData = client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key).clone();
        try {
            // cloning metadata so that overwritten file has same metadata as original file
            client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file).withMetadata(objMData));
        } catch(AmazonClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is my test method:

```
@Mock
private AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client();

public void testUpload() {

    S3Uploader uploader = new S3Uploader(client);

    File testFile = new File("file.txt");
    String filename = "file.txt";
    String bucketname = "buckettest";
    String account = "account";

    String key = account+filename;
    ObjectMetadata objMetadata = Mockito.mock(ObjectMetadata.class);
    when(client.getObjectMetadata(bucketname, key).clone()).thenReturn(objectMetadata);

    // can I make this line do nothing? doNothing()??
    doNothing.when(client.putObject(Matchers.eq(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file).withMetadata(objMData))));

    uploader.upload(aFile, anAccount, bucketName);

    // how do I verify that methods were called correctly??
    // what can I assert here?

}
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at the line in my test

```
when(client.getObjectMetadata(bucketname, key).clone()).thenReturn(objectMetadata);
```

I'm not even able to reach the method call. Honestly, what I'm pretty much asking is, how do I verify that this `upload()` method is correct?

Comment: Do you know the exact names of exceptions that you'd want to catch?

Answer (score 8):

The method you showed in your question uses a `client` instance to talk to S3. The `client` instance in the class to which this method belongs is either injected (at construction time, for example) or created (via a factory, perhaps). Assuming it is injected when the containing class is created then your test case might look like this:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    AmazonS3 client = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3.class);

    S3Uploader uploader = new S3Uploader(client);

    String bucketName = "aBucketName";

    // ensures that the getObjectMetadata call fails thereby throwing the exception which your method catches
    Mockito.when(client.getObjectMetadata(Matchers.eq(bucketName), Matchers.eq("fakekey")).thenThrow(new AmazonServiceException());

    uploader.uploadToS3(aFile, anAccount, bucketName);

    // at this stage you would typically assert that the response 
    // from the upload invocation is valid but as things stand 
    // upload() swallows the exception so there's nothing to assert against
}


@Test
public void testSomethingElse() {
    AmazonS3 client = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3.class);

    S3Uploader uploader = new S3Uploader(client);

    String bucketName = "aBucketName";
    String key = "fakekey";
    File aFile = ...;
    ObjectMetadata objMData = ...;

    // ensures that the getObjectMetadata call succeeds thereby allowing the call to continue to the subsequent putObject invocation
    Mockito.when(client.getObjectMetadata(eq(bucketName), eq(key)).thenReturn(objMData);

    // ensures that the putObject call fails thereby throwing the exception which your method catches
    Mockito.when(client.putObject(Matchers.eq(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file).withMetadata(objMData)).thenThrow(new AmazonServiceException());

    uploader.uploadToS3(aFile, anAccount, bucketName);

    // at this stage you would typically assert that the response 
    // from the upload invocation is valid but as things stand 
    // upload() swallows the exception so there's nothing to assert against
}
```

The above code uses [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) to mock the AmazonS3 client, this allows you to tweak the behaviour of your `client` instance such that your test invocations go down the 'throw exception' paths.

On a side note the catch clauses look a little odd since `AmazonS3.putObject` and `AmazonS3.getObjectMetadata` are both declared to throw `AmazonServiceException` and `AmazonServiceException` extends `AmazonClientException`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my post to provide more context and changed my question a little bit. I'm a bit new to unit tests so still working through the docs to understand it more, but at the end, I just want to write a test that would be able to cover this upload() method.

Comment: Looking at your updated answer the likeliest causes of the NPE at this line: `when(client.getObjectMetadata(bucketname, key).clone()).thenReturn(objectMetadata)` are either: (1) `client` is null or (2) the `getObjectMetadata` call returns null. Can you confirm that `client` is not null i.e. that you successfully supplied a mocked instance of it? If `client` is not null then the issue is likely to be the parameters you supplied in the mocked `getObjectMetadata` call. They should be "fakekey" and the variable `bucketname` but in your mock call you are using `account+filename` and  `bucketname`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use this project https://github.com/findify/s3mock.
Create a mock of S3 bucket, and then you can test what happens when the bucket you look for exist or not.